# How do I create a check constraint on a zip code?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've seen some documentation on how to run the check using sql server using the replicate function. It doesn't look like MY SQL doesn't have a replicate function but they have a similar function called repeat. However, when I try to implement the check constraint, it errors.

```
create table Customer_Dim(
customer_ID     int not null,
FirstName       varchar(30) not null,
LastName        varchar(30) not null,
Gender          char(1) not null CHECK (gender in ('m','f')),
Street1         varchar(100) not null,
Street2         varchar(100) not null,
City            varchar(30) not null,
StateAbbrev     char(2) not null,
ZipCode         char(5) not null,
PrimaryPhone    varchar(10) not null,
EmailAddress    varchar(50) default null,
constraint custkey Primary Key(customer_ID),
CONSTRAINT zipchk CHECK (ZipCode LIKE repeat('[0-9]',5));
```

I get the error

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 14 but the red x is by the constraint line.

Comment: First you need MySQL version 8+. Then try `CHECK (ZipCode regexp '^[0-9]{5}$')`

Answer (score 0):

The Like function worked, I just missed some syntax at the end.

```
create table Customer_Dim(
customer_ID     int not null,
FirstName       varchar(30) not null,
LastName        varchar(30) not null,
Gender          char(1) not null CHECK (gender in ('m','f')),
Street1         varchar(100) not null,
Street2         varchar(100) not null,
City            varchar(30) not null,
StateAbbrev     char(2) not null,
ZipCode         char(5) not null CHECK (ZipCode LIKE repeat('[0-9]',5)),
PrimaryPhone    varchar(10) not null CHECK (PrimaryPhone LIKE repeat('[0-9]',10)),
EmailAddress    varchar(50) default null,
constraint custkey Primary Key(customer_ID)
); <----
```